# Interactive matplotlib using ipywidgets

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I want to implement an *interactive plot* using **Matplotlib** and **ipywidgets** in IPython (python3). So, how I can do this efficiently (change smoothly without delay)?

And another question is why this code works?!

```
from ipywidgets import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi)

def update(w = 1.0):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
    ax.plot(x, np.sin(w * x))

    fig.canvas.draw()

interact(update);
```

[image]

But, this doesn't work?!

```
from ipywidgets import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
line, = ax.plot(x, np.sin(x))

def update(w = 1.0):
    line.set_ydata(np.sin(w * x))
    fig.canvas.draw()

interact(update);
```

[image]

Comment: Did you ever find a way to get the second example to work? I have the same problem right now.

Answer (score 8):

The second approach is the right one for the notebook backend

```
%matplotlib notebook
```

Or with ipympl.

However, it won't work with the inline backend which does not update the plot.

Comment: For me, the second approach does not work for the notebook backend. No graph is shown at all.

Comment: I recommend using ipympl (aka jupyter-matplotlib), which is the notebook backend split into a separate package. The reason for the split is that release cycles of Jupyter are much faster than matplotlib. ipympl is separated from matplotlib to be able to track this better.

Comment: Also, `fig.show()` is necessary in order to show the canvas.