# How can I update matplotlib plot in ipywidget with interactive mode on?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I am writing a Jupyter notebook that reads data from a sensor and I want to plot it as it is read. Data should start plotting when the user clicks a button.
I tested the base code in the Spyder IDE and it works properly, but when I try to implement it on a Jupyter notebook it doesn't work properly.

Here's a MWE of my code. I kept the button, to show what I am trying to achieve.

```
import numpy as np
import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipywidgets import interactive
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import display

BotGraf = widgets.ToggleButton(value=False,
    description='Graficar',
    disabled=False,
    button_style='info',
    tooltip='Description',
    icon='chart-line'
)

SalidaEjes = widgets.Output(layout=widgets.Layout(width="75%"))

def FBotGraf(ValBotGraf):
    if ValBotGraf == True:
        global NumEl
        global d
        NumEl = np.arange(0, 100)
        d = np.zeros(100)
        plt.ion()

        with SalidaEjes:
            fig = plt.figure()
            ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
            line1, = ax.plot(NumEl, d, 'r-')
            plt.show()

            i=0

            while i < 100:
                d[i] = np.random.rand()
                line1.set_ydata(d)
                fig.canvas.draw()
                fig.canvas.flush_events()
                plt.show()
                i += 1
        
IBotGraf = interactive(FBotGraf, ValBotGraf = BotGraf)

display(BotGraf)
display(SalidaEjes)
```

This way the plot shows up but plots the original data `d = np.zeros(100)` and doesn't update the plot.

In the following cell however if I try to plot it:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
line1, = ax.plot(NumEl, d, 'r-')
```

It shows that `d` was in fact update in the cycle.
[image: plot of d outside the cycle and the function]

I read these questions:
[Interactive Graph with matplotlib and ipywidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44180957/interactive-graph-with-matplotlib-and-ipywidget) and
[Interactive matplotlib using ipywidgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40122837/interactive-matplotlib-using-ipywidgets).
But either didn't apply them properly or didn't solve the problem.

I guess it's not a complicated problem, but I can't figure it out.

Thanks for reading!